# FXKeychain-ios example project doesn't work and it doesn't compile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on a project that uses the library 'FXKeychain' that i downloaded from here: 
     [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOUT7.png): https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain
This lib cams with some examples projects but the project does not compile.

Is it any prerequisites in order to run this project/ use this lib??. maybe come component installed in the computer 
Thanks in advance![image: This capture show the errors that i'm having]

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old Xcode version. Upgrade to Xcode 6.3. If you don't see the upgrade, you are probably running an old OS X version; you need OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) for Xcode 6.3.